# Connect Telegram Bot to google sheet

Tags: python, heroku, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api, gspread

I run python script in a heroku to connect telegram bot to the google sheet. I use google sheet API for that to save message from the bot to the sheet. Every time i use the bot I get this error as in the [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPWja.png).

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
2018-07-31T10:37:11.672178+00:00 app[dana_bot.1]:   "error": {
2018-07-31T10:37:11.672179+00:00 app[dana_bot.1]:     "code": 401,
2018-07-31T10:37:11.672181+00:00 app[dana_bot.1]:     "message": 
"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access 
token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
2018-07-31T10:37:11.672183+00:00 app[dana_bot.1]:     "status": 
"UNAUTHENTICATED"
2018-07-31T10:37:11.672184+00:00 app[dana_bot.1]:   }
2018-07-31T10:37:11.672185+00:00 app[dana_bot.1]: }
2018-07-31T10:37:11.672186+00:00 app[dana_bot.1]:
```

i tried to use the OAuth 2.0 client with gspread but failed? if anyone can help me with that i will be thankful.

this is the code which i use for authentication

```
import telebot
import gspread
import datetime
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('DanaBot.json', 
scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets')
```

Comment: can you post the code you use for authentication?

Comment: I would suggest that you give the [Python Quickstart Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) to have insight of the OAuth2.0 flow in Sheets API and Google API in general before moving on to integrating other 3rd party applications.